# background colors in matrix table

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using a matrix table with drill downs.  My Priority2015 column contains Gold Silver and Bronze.  I would like the Gold background to appear yellow (which i've got working), Silver to be silver and Bronze as Bronze.  Ideally I would like the colored backgrounds too follow through across the months but no matter if not possible.

[image]

I have used this expression to get the yellow background

```
 =IIF(Fields!Priority2015.Value = "Gold", "Yellow", "No Color" )
```

I've tried doing this to get the silver it but didn't work

```
=IIF(Fields!Priority2015.Value = "Gold", "Yellow", "No Color", Fields!   Priority2015.Value = "Silver", "Silver", "No Color" )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your matrix select the entire row, press `F4` to see the properties window, look for the `Fill` node and set the background color property to the below expression.

[image]  [image]

```
=Switch(
  Fields!Priority2015.Value="Gold","Yellow",
  Fields!Priority2015.Value="Silver","Silver",
  Fields!Priority2015.Value="Bronze","Bronze",
  true,"No color"
)
```

It will apply the background color property to the entire row.

Let me know if this helps.